# Diode AM detector linearity

Tags: amplitude-modulation, vintage

Most valve radios use a vacuum tube diode as a detector. Over the decades, I have used germanium diodes with good apparent performance. In other words, cheap equipment sounds good when the germanium diode is properly biased. My question is about the vacuum tube diode.

Is the vacuum tube diode more linear than the biased semiconductor diode?

On one hand the Richardson equation for the vacuum diode might give nice even harmonic distortion. The exponential for the Ge diode will give odd and even harmonics but bias helps and the Ge diode has less voltage drop at normal signal levels like say 2 VDC detected halfwave from 455 kHz.

Comment: I guess you are excluding the gas filled types. Then yes, the vacuum tube diode curve has a fairly flat slope in the space-charge limit area of operation. I'm not looking at a datasheet for one right now. But I seem to recall the I-V curve as being rather 'line-like' over a fair part of the forward voltage difference region. (Obviously, once the space charge is completely depleted then the current will flatten off to the rate allowed by thermionic emission.) Do you have a datasheet to look at?

Comment: I'm not very much from the tube-as-RF-receiver-component era, but: Since tubes were built for different purposes and operating regions, my understanding is that they have very different characteristic curves (just as semiconductor diodes,but over greater ranges). It might be sensible to look at any given receiver architecture and infer what type of vacuum diode would be used in that, but you'll likely find a semiconductor device that is more linear than the diode over the same input range. Would "taking a specific vacuum device and comparing it to the most linear semiconductor device" be fair?

Comment: Vacuum tube characteristic is something like : current ... I^3/2) vs anode voltage https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Current-voltage-characteristics-of-a-vacuum-tube-illustrating-the-3-2-power-law-Eq-8_fig2_1832104 As semiconductors are generally "exponential" law, vacuum tubes are "more" linear and less "distortion" vs interferences.

Comment: @MarcusMüller With appropriate use of NFB semiconductor diodes would be more linear. But I thought their question was more about open-loop as it included a statement about first setting up an operating point. Maybe I misunderstood the context, though, since very little was said about that except 'detector'.

Comment: @jonk yeah, considering the question open-loop makes more sense, now that I think about it.